# Unupvote immediately followed by an upvote gives me a net -10 reputation points

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

This can be seen on [my reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263525/dystroy?tab=reputation):

This sequence resulted in a 10 points reputation loss:

```
     12 mins ago    upvote  Javascript load images in canvas with JCanvaScript
-10  12 mins ago    unupvote    Javascript load images in canvas with JCanvaScript
```

(Unupvote is first)

Why? Is that a bug as I imagine?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Correction to my now deleted comment. This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

The upvote was initially cast on a day when you were not repcapped. It was revoked and recast today where you *are* repcapped.

- When the upvote is revoked, you lose it on the day it was cast. (as if it never happened)
- When the upvote is recast today, it counts towards today.

But you're capped today. Hence, you don't get that +10 back.

The net effect of unupvoting and immediately reupvoting is that the vote is "moved" from the old date to today. You were unfortunate enough to have your repcaps in the wrong place.

Comment: Is it by design that when a user clicks on a button and undoes I lose some rep ? If he does it 10 other times, what will happen ?

Comment: When a vote is undone, it's as if it never existed. It's erased from the day it was cast. (which also happens to be a day you were not repcapped)

Comment: Is it "by design" or "an unfortunate feature that would be to hard to fix" ? Because unupvote followed immediately by an upvote seems like it should be a no-op.

Comment: Note that by the same reasoning, if you were at the repcap on the older day and not today you would have gained 10 rep from the unupvote/upvote

Comment: Which I would also consider as a bug (and a breach).

Comment: I agree with that. Nick mentions that the current rep system is already complicated enough. So making exceptions like this will make it even more messy. In any case, this actually works both ways. I've gained +10s a few times from unupvotes immediately followed by reupvotes.

Comment: Yes, I understand this would be complicated to fix. And probably not necessary. But asserting a bug is really a bug helps to list them all and, in a possible future, when changing the system, have it in mind. Just because a bug is very painful to fix doesn't mean it should be classified as feature. It could be classified as "bug, won't fix".

Comment: @dystroy I don't consider it a bug.  Just because something seems unintuitive doesn't make it a bug.  You didn't click 'undo' and then 'redo', you clicked 'undo' and then redid the original action.  There is no button for undo the unto (aka redo).  It just so happens that performing that same action at a later date may have a different effect (because of just being on a different day).  Therefore I would consider it a feature to wrap all voting that takes place within X minutes as a transaction (thus turning a upvote/unupvote into a no-op).

Comment: I think it would be interesting to get some statistics on how many times this has resulting in +10 vs. -10. When people get +10s they usually don't bring it up on meta. I'm tempted to think it results in +10 more often than -10. (for me it certainly does)

Comment: Does it matter?  As long as we don't see people trying to game the system by tactically re-doing votes to increase/decrease someone else's rep I don't see any significant negative consequences.