# Reputation Tab mismatched with Upvote count on Answer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I was wondering why I have `-2` on the reputation tab as seen below

[image]

but when I navigate on the question, there was no downvote.

[image]

The question can be found here: [Each separate id's count in mysql in two table with join query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636685/each-separate-ids-count-in-mysql-in-two-table-with-join-query/15636838#15636838)

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

If you expand the arrow, you can see:

```
+10 2 hours ago     upvote   
-2  2 hours ago     unupvote
```

Somebody who had previously upvoted on a different day undid the upvote and then immediately reupvoted.

The initial upvote probably finished off your repcap with a +2 on a different day. So when it was undone, it was reverted. Then the reupvote gave you +10.

Comment: hello there, I have updated the image. The first image I posted was from visitors view, and the updated one is the user's view. The maximum reputation I got so far today is only upto `288` (*deducted*) from I downvoted. Isn't it I will gain `+2` for the next upvote? But in this case I can't and that is what I'm wondering.

Comment: No. The when a vote is undone, it is removed from the day it was cast. Therefore it is subject to the repcap of the original day rather than today.

Comment: Here's another related question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144512/unupvote-immediately-followed-by-an-upvote-gives-me-a-net-10-reputation-points

Comment: I think that is not the case here. I got another upvote from one of my answers and I didn't gain any reputation (*i have updated the image again*). So that does mean my highest reputation I can get today is only `288` if I cannot get any accepted answer reputation? As far as I know, I can gain back a reputation if the repcap limit is not yet reached.

Comment: The -2 applies to a different day. But it is shown on your profile as today. Suppose you had a day with 198. Then an upvote finishes it off to 200. Then the next day, that upvote is undone. So you lose those 2 points permanently - regardless of your repcap status today.

Comment: If you read my answer on the question I linked to, the that upvote is effectively "moved" from a previous day to today. So if it moves from a day that you were not capped to a day that you are, then it's a net loss.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the timeline as logged by the system:

- Upvote yesterday: +2
- Unupvote today: -2
- Upvote today: +10

This is consistent with what you see (yesterday you were repcapped).