# When will my reputation update?

Tags: support, bug, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

On [Programming Puzzles and Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), my reputation is shown as 10 less than it should be, in every place it is shown.

[image][image][image]

The reputation should be 11,077. The -10 rep is because the system thinks I only got +190 yesterday:

[image]

Which should not be, because I clearly got upvotes after the unupvote, and several upvotes that did not count because I hit the rep cap.

Furthermore, when I visit the reputation page (codegolf.stackexchange.com/reputation), that lists my rep correctly as 11,077. It also says that I gained 200 yesterday, not 190:

```
-- 2014-07-10 rep +200  = 10877
Data that I think I might not be supposed to show...
-- 2014-07-11 rep +200  = 11077
```

<sub>Note: if I should copy more of the page, please tell me. However, I think that that information is not supposed to be public.</sub>

The error started yesterday, and I assumed the system simply hadn't updated yet. But this seems to be not the case. When will the system update and change the displayed rep to the real rep?

Comment: You seem to be talking specifically about your flair. Is that the case?

Comment: @Oded It's not just my flair. The error is everywhere my rep is displayed on the site. I'll add more pics.

Comment: It should recalculate within a day or so...

Comment: @hichris123 Like when? I saw this error >12 hours ago, well before the change of the UTC day.

Comment: @Oded This happens all the time for me. The recalc only happens if the unupvote happens when you are currently repcapped. When the correct behavior is that the recalc should run if you were repcapped on the day that the vote was cast. I've gone for weeks with a discrepancy between my actual rep and my audit page. Since the manual recalc button has been removed, the only way to force a recalc is to delete/undelete something.

Comment: @Mysticial Are you saying I should post a terrible post to attract downvotes, then delete it? :-)

Comment: @Quincunx lol no. :) Just find any one of your answers that isn't accepted and delete/undelete it.

Comment: @Oded FWIW, I currently have a 20 rep descrepancy between my actual rep and my audit page (not that I particularly care). They're all from unupvotes. [I asked Shog about this a while back](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1424811#1424811) and he thinks it's a bug.

Comment: @Mysticial I did as you suggested; now my reputation is displayed correctly!

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Unupvote immediately followed by an upvote gives me a net -10 reputation points](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144512/168244)

Comment: @Werner I'm pretty sure this isn't a duplicate. In that question, the user was confused as to the -10 points from unupvote when it was immediately followed by an upvote. Here, I am confused why the reputation was not displaying correctly.

Comment: @Quincunx: It's a similar cause in my opinion - an un-upvote leads to a different display of reputation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a bug in the trigger for the repcalc script.

Ever since [Nick rolled out the new rep system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes), anything that can cause your rep to get out-of-sync will trigger a recalc. So it should be impossible for your actual rep to stay out-of-sync.

But Shog as [confirmed a possible bug](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1424811#1424811) in the logic that determines when a recalc should be done.

**Correct Behavior:** When a vote is retracted, perform recalc if the user was repcapped on the day when the vote was cast.

**Actual Behavior:** When a vote is retracted, perform recalc if the user is currently repcapped.

---

So the following sequence of events will cause your rep to get out-of-sync:

1. Day 1: Get 21 answer upvotes. This will repcap you to 200 rep.
2. Day 2: Retract one of the upvotes from Day 1 that were cast *before* hitting the repcap. Make sure you are not repcapped when the upvote is retracted.
3. You will now have a 10 rep discrepancy between visible rep and audit rep.

Here's what happened:

- When the vote was cast, it gave +10.
- When the vote is retracted, it sees that it gave +10 and thus deducts 10 from the visible rep.
- However, even without that vote, the user had enough "over the cap" votes to compensate for it.
- The result is that the visible rep gets -10, but the audit rep stays the same. The recalc is supposed to fix this, but it didn't run.

The visible rep and audit rep will stay out-of-sync until something else triggers a recalc.

Comment: I don't know *for sure* if this is what's actually happening. But it happens to me about twice a month - add that up over a year or so and it's enough data points for me to reach this conclusion.