# unvote plus upvote across time

Tags: discussion, bug, voting, daily-reputation-limit

I was over the rep limit yesterday (30 minutes ago).  After the new day began, I edited an answer.  Someone who had up-voted my answer while I was over my limit, un-voted the same answer on the new day.  Consequently, I saw no reputation gain.  This made sense.  However, same person subsequently re-up-voted the answer and I got +10.  ***This does not make sense***

I can't justify why this should be the case and can be easily exploited.  How easy would it be to fix?

Comment: [This has been the case forever.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144512/unupvote-immediately-followed-by-an-upvote-gives-me-a-net-10-reputation-points) But, I mean it doesn't seem any more abuse-able then the ability to edit-remove-vote. And it's not like this is happening so much that it causes problems.

Comment: Yeah, that was a while ago.  The exploit would be that I can borrow from yesterday's votes to smooth out rep.  You say it isn't happening so much that it causes a problem.  Does that imply that if it did happen often, you would see that as a problem and since its not happening often, its low priority.  Plus, the people who would be able to exploit it are the ones most likely not to want to.  I added a few more thoughts, but is that basically what you're saying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't see anything to fix here, everything works just fine and as expected.

When removing the vote, it's just removed as if it never existed. Usually you lose reputation as a result, but in case of rep cap, as you observed yourself, you don't lose any reputation because you did not get any to begin with, due to that vote.

Now, when casting the vote again, **this is a whole new vote**. The system does not, and should not, check if the same user voted in the past. So whatever was in place in the past, no longer applies.